# LilyPond: different clefs for each voice on one staff

Tags: lilypond

Here is the desired engraving:

[image]

See how the tied D continues in the bass clef while the left-hand staff switches to the treble clef. Is it possible to engrave with LilyPond?

Here is a MWE I tried:

```
\version "2.24.2"
\language "italiano"

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \key re \minor
        \numericTimeSignature
        \time 3/4
        \clef bass
        \relative do' {
            <<
                {
                    s2. r4 r8. \clef treble
                    \tuplet 3/2 16 { sol'32 (la sib }
                    do8.) do16--
                    do16-- sib sol la
                    sol8. 
                    \omit TupletBracket
                    \tuplet 3/2 16 { fa32 (sol la }
                    sib8.) sib16
                } \\
                {
                    \stemUp re,,,8.-- re16-- re2--~ 2.~
                    \stemNeutral
                    2.~ 2.
                }
            >>
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

I also tried removing `Clef_engraver` from the staff context and adding it to the voice context. It didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
\version "2.24.2"
\language "italiano"

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \accepts "PseudoStaff"
  }
  \context {
    \name "PseudoStaff"
    \type Engraver_group
    \alias "Staff"
    \consists "Clef_engraver"
    \clef "GG" % Anything odd, just to mask clef changes in superior staff
    \override Clef.font-size = #-3
  }
}
    

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \key re \minor
        \numericTimeSignature
        \time 3/4
        \clef bass
        \relative do' {
            <<
                {
                    s2. r4 r8. \clef treble
                    \tuplet 3/2 16 { sol'32 (la sib }
                    do8.) do16--
                    do16-- sib sol la
                    sol8. 
                    \omit TupletBracket
                    \tuplet 3/2 16 { fa32 (sol la }
                    sib8.) sib16
          } \\
        << \new PseudoStaff = "ps" { \once \omit Clef \skip 2.*4 }
                {
          \stemUp re,,,8.-- re16-- re2--~ 2.~
          \change Staff = "ps"
          \once \override Staff.Clef.Y-offset = #-3
          \clef "bass"
          \stemNeutral
          2.~ 2.
                }
         >>
            >>
        }
    }
}
```

with the respective context definition for `\midi` left as an exercise to the reader (since pitches are already entered at-pitch, you won't need much more than just the definitions for the `\layout` context hierarchy while using `Performer_group` instead of `Engraver_group`).

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand the code, and, thus, I don't understand how to fix the warnings when `\midi` is present. Your instructions on how to do it sound to me like Chinese.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if there is a line break. A second clef appears at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4):

A look into the [LilyPond Snippet Repository](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/) (LSR) usually helps – if you search for 'clef', the second hit is [Combining pedal notes with clef changes](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=326), which might give an alternative solution:

[image]